# Adding dynamic widgets to a panel (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, onclick

I'm having trouble adding a variable amount of labels to a panel. My problem is that for some reason when adding my `ClickListener` it returns `void` instead of widget (error).  If I just have "new Label('xyz')" that works fine, but I need each panel to have their own `ClickListener` as well.  Here is the code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < productIDArray.length(); x++) {
  mainPanel.add(new Label("Test").addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(Widget sender) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
  }));
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned value from method chaining is always the last value. If you change new `A().b().c()`, the returned type will be c's return type.

In your example, the return type of `new Label("Test").addClickListener(...` is the ClickListener's addClickListener return type, which is void.

You can create the label, add the click listener and then add it:

```
for(int x = 0;x<productIDArray.length();x++) {
  Label l = new Label("Test);
  l.addClickListener(...);
  mainPanel.add(l);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that it would just continue to add the same label or throw an error because of the loop but I see that is not the case.